# How to detect if where has no result

Tags: javascript, sqlite

My code

```
stmt.bind({$ticket:"ABCD1245"});
while (stmt.step()) console.log(stmt.get());
```

gives a result like [1], that is correct

```
stmt.bind({$ticket:"ABCD1245a"});
while (stmt.step()) console.log(stmt.get());
```

gives no result at all, which is ok, because no record exist.

How do i detect if no record was found, i tried like stmt.numrows, but looks like thats not supported.

Comment: Instead of logging the result, push it to an array. Then check the length of the array.

Comment: @ChrisG Where do i do that, stmt.step() gives no result, so there is nothing to push.

Comment: 1. declare the results array `const r = [];` 2. `while (stmt.step()) r.push(stmt.get());` 3. `if (r.length === 0) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way, would like to use stmt.num_rows

```
ticket= "ABCD1245A";
        stmt.bind({$ticket:ticket});
        if(stmt.step()){
            console.log(stmt.get());
            console.log(ticket+' found');
            while (stmt.step()) console.log(stmt.get());
        }else{
            console.log('No result for '+ticket);
        }
```